# How can we find the arc length of the curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

How can I find the length of the curve
$$\left(\frac{t^3}{3} - t\right)\mathbf{i}+ t^2 \mathbf{j}, \quad 0≤t≤1?$$

Comment: When we do the calculation, if we do not make a minor slip, the thing inside the square root turns out, "miraculously," to be a perfect square. Change the numbers a little and you will get something you can't integrate in elementary terms.

Answer (score 3):

Length of a curve from $t=a$ and $t=b$ is given by
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} dt$$
provided $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ exists and are continuous.

In your problem, $x(t) = \dfrac{t^3}3 - t$, $y(t) = t^2$, $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: @BabakSorouh True. I will update it.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. this helped me to much.